# Freeze animation at a specific frame

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, animation, freeze

I need some help . I work at a 2d unity game which have a fluffy ball as the main character . This fluffy ball have a hand component ( child ) which have a animation . Each individual frame have a box collider property .This hand will be activated when i press E and that animation will start in the direction where my cursor is . So , the problem is next : I want that hand to grab stuffs . Like a box . Here i ask for your help . i tried to figure out how i can freeze the aniamation for a short time , like 5 seconds or till i press again E ,  when the box collider of that specific frame collide with a object (e.g. ground or box ).Here is the script of the hand :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class facingScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SpriteRenderer render;
    private Camera mainCam;
    private Vector3 mousePos;
    private Animator aniHand;


    public bool freezeAniamtion = false;

    void Start()
    {
        render = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        mainCam = Camera.main;
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        aniHand = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, mainCam.transform.position.z - transform.position.z));
        
        Vector3 rotation = mousePos - transform.position;
        if(rotation.x > 0)
            render.flipY = true;
        else
            render.flipY = false;

    
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) 
            {
            aniHand.Play("CharacterHand");
            }
            

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "box")
        {
            StartCoroutine(HandCollide());
            // help pls :) 
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator HandCollide(float waitTime)
    {
        // idk what i should put here :P 
    }

    
    
}`
```

I try with aniHand.speed but it dont do nothing and  with PlayInFixedTime but idk how it work

Comment: You could probably simply `aniHand.enabled = false` and later activate it again?

Comment: Not at a PC right now but you might need to additionally track how long the animation was already playing and after re-enabling the animator pass in according start time and call again `aniHand.Play("CharacterHand", normalizedTime: XY );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So . I fugire it out some how . I have another script that activate and dezactivate my hand for 1 second. And when I try to stop my animation în hand script it just turn of from that another script

Comment: You could mark it as the answer.